# Tokens not entered when using default Drupal CKEditor (with module Wysiwyg)

Tags: drupal, tokens, wysiwyg, ckeditor

This question was already in the old forum. But no answers and I have the problem.

Set up details:
Drupal 7.latest and civicrm 4.6.2 series
Drupal CKEditor is installed in a 'libraries' subdirectory of sites > all.
the Drupal module Wysiwyg is installed to make the link to the CKEditor installed in the libraries directory.(This is done so that CKEditor doesn't have to be re-installed every time there is a Drupal update.)
'Use default Drupal' in the site preferences field that selects the Wysiwyg editor

Problem:

It is not possible to select CiviCRM tokens in the rich text editor
You can enter them by hand, or enter them into the plain text area then copy and paste them.
With CiviCRM's own CKEditor you can also select tokens as expected.

Presumably the problem is in the Wysiwyg module - it needs a plugin for CiviCRM in the same way that it needs a plugin for IMCE.

Temporary work-arounds for admins pulling their hair out...
1) use civirm's own CKEditor installation (sites settings)
2) tell users to use the plain text editor to find the token, then cut and paste into the rich text editor.

Request

Can anyone 
a) confirm this is the case (that a plugin is needed) - or is there a simpler solution?
b) has anyone made such a plugin, or 
c) have a really good handle on how to make one?

Regards,
HashKey